# JavaScriptCore evaluateScript cannot handle objects?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, iphone, javascriptcore

I am working with `JSContext` and the rest of JavaScriptCore. Can anybody explain to me why evaluateScript fails in the second assertion?

```
let context = JSContext()!
let obj1    = context.evaluateScript("[{ 'first': 'Grace', 'last': 'Hopper', 'year': 1906 }]")
assert(obj1?.isArray ?? false)
let obj2    = context.evaluateScript(" { 'first': 'Grace', 'last': 'Hopper', 'year': 1906 } ")
assert(obj2?.isObject ?? false)
```

Why does wrapping an object in an array works, but the raw objects does not work?

Comment: When a statement starts with `{` it's assumed to be a block statement, not an object initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out a script starting with `{` is evaluating as a block, instead of an object. This is the workaround for now:

```
let obj2 = context.evaluateScript("[{ 'first': 'Grace', 'last': 'Hopper', 'year': 1906 }]")
assert(obj2?.objectAtIndexedSubscript(0)?.isObject ?? false)
```

Basically wrapping it in an array, and unwrapping the first object. Works fine